# A good book for learning mathematical trickery

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, big-list

I've seen several question here on what book to read to learn writing and reading proofs. This question is *not* about that. I've been doing that for a while, and I'm quite comfortable with proofs. I am looking for resources (books, ideally) that can teach not the concept of proofs, but rather some of the specific mathematical tricks that are commonly employed in proofs: those that mostly include clever number manipulation, ad-hoc integration techniques, numerical methods and other thing you are likely *never* to learn in theory-oriented books. I come mainly from applied math and engineering, and when I look at proofs from Stochastic Processes, Digital Signal Processing, Non-Linear Systems and other applied subjects, I feel like I need to learn a new method to understand every proof I read. Is there any good literature on such mathematical tricks?

Comment: "numerical methods" - you'll pick up a whole lot of practical numerical advice/tricks of the trade from Acton's two books: *[Numerical Methods That (usually) Work](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0883854503)* and *[Real Computing Made Real](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486442217)*.

Comment: You might also be interested in *[The Art and Craft of Problem Solving](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0471789011)*.

Comment: Wait until you see set theoretic proofs :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check them out. All of them look great. You should post these as answers, I'll upvote = )

Comment: @Asaf Looking forward to it, one day = )

Comment: @Phonon: can you be more specific about these examples you describe? I'm not really sure what "clever number manipulation" or "ad-hoc integration techniques" could be referring to. More generally, beyond a handful of very general things the "tricks" you're going to see will depend on the field (although not necessarily in an obvious way), so I wouldn't say that there are "proof tricks" so much as "tricks for certain kinds of proofs."

Comment: @Qiaochu I have to look at some books and type up several examples.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if you're interested in inequalities, but a very nice book which teaches lots of tricks is Steele's [*The Cauchy–Schwarz Master Class*](http://books.google.com/books?id=7GDyRMrlgDsC&pg=PP1).

Comment: This looks very good. Much closer to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11):

I enjoyed Mahajan's *Street-Fighting Mathematics*.  It has a strongly "applied" bent, and is [freely available](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-098-street-fighting-mathematics-january-iap-2008/).

Answer (score 10):

The [Tricki](http://www.tricki.org/) ("Trick Wiki") is an attempt to catalogue such things, although it is somewhat less successful than was initially hoped.

Comment: This is great! = ) Thanks! Not exactly what I'm looking for, but indeed very promising.